# Best way to store stream data

Tags: c++, stream, boost-serialization

I'm making a game message system and using boost::serialize to convert message data into streams and sending it. This works fine for transmitting messages instantly as I can send off the reference to the stream.

However I would like to queue up messages as well in some circumstances. I am not sure what the best way to store the data would be.

I tried `std::queue<std::stringstream>` but that just errors lots.

std::bitset looks semi promising, but I'm not sure.

Or is this completely bonkers?

Comment: whats wrong with a std::vector or std::queue?

Comment: I get loads of errors when I do std::queue<std::stringstream>

Comment: Using stream for in process message passing is not such a good idea. The stream writing and reading is an unnecessary overhead which can be avoided by introducing of the message types and message pools.

Comment: @Sasha Honestly thats what I thought, but a book recommended it, I am doing it as an exercise. Perviously I was passing around void* and casting them, but that didn't feel right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `std::queue<std::vector<char> >`.  The stringstream you tried before isn't copyable, so just copy the bytes.  You could also use string as the value type in the queue, since that's probably what you'll be getting out of the stringstream.